# Generate an image ( jpg or png or webp ) from a file content with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, google-drive-shared-drive

Google Drive somehow generating an image from the uploaded files like txt or pdf,
and it also shows a preview / thumbnail about the file contents like an image.

Here is a reference picture from google drive

[image]

How can i create an image of a file's content server side with NodeJS?

Comment: for each file type it uses an appropriate library to read the file and make a picture of it. you can imagine that you'd need a library to read *and render* PDFs, a library to read *and render* word documents, ... -- this is actual work. this won't be doable with a handful of library calls

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will leave this question in case if any miracle happens.